# Reset network interface in Linux

Tags: linux

I have a vmware machine that runs RHEL5 and it has 2 NICs eth0 and eth1. When I clone (copy) this machine, my NICs are changed as:

```
eth0 becomes eth2 
eth1 becomes eth3
```

How should I do to recover all NICs back to eth0 and eth1?

Comment: This does belong to stack [superuser](http://superuser.com/) so don't get discouraged when you get few down-votes. Just wait 'till it get moved. This really is not a programming question whatsoever :).

Comment: Wouln't it better to formulate this question on ServerFault?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is common when you clone a virtual machine. udev renames your interfaces while booting. You can edit the udev rules in file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`. It is better to read the vmware kbase

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1032790

Answer (score 3):

In modern Linux systems kernel names for devices are often corrected by udev ( look for /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules ) or similar.

When system boots up first time, HW addresses of network cards are saved to ensure e.g. if they will be replaced on motherboard or new physical interface added, previously existing interfaces will still have same "ethX" system name. This way network card with aa:aa:bb:cc.. will always be "eth2" in system, for example even if kernel previously was recognizing it as eth1 and now it recognizes it as eth4 due to some change of physical configuration of hardware.

When you create a clone of virtual system (obviously including all files on all its filesystems), pseudo-physical devices get new HW address, while HW addresses they had in originating system are still reserved for eth0 and eth1 - that is why when kernel of clones detect these cards, it assigns them eth2 and eth3 names.

Some VM environments have options of cloning, which allows choosing if clone should keep previously used HW addresses, or new shall be generated/assigned. Also, most VM environments allow arbitral setting of HW addresses of virtual network cards.